# No description for object of class "stuff" in symfony

Tags: symfony1, max, doctrine-query

I'm trying to execute this:

```
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
      ->select('MAX(s.ID) AS max')
      ->from('stuff s')
      ->execute();
```

I'm getting: No description for object of class "stuff".
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find it.
It was fetchOne() instead of execute().
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

***user1038382:***

Go to the definition of your class, at lib\model\doctrine , and add the following function inside the class:

```
public function __toString() {
   parent::__toString();
   return $this->getNameOfTheFieldYouWantToDisplay();
}
```